# Keras loss function understanding

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nan, loss

In order to understand some callbacks of Keras better, I want to artificially create a `nan` loss.

This is the function

```
def soft_dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):

  from keras import backend as K
  if K.eval(K.random_normal((1, 1), mean=2, stddev=2))[0][0] // 1 == 2.0:
    # return nan
    return K.exp(1.0) / K.exp(-10000000000.0) - K.exp(1.0) / K.exp(-10000000000.0)

  epsilon = 1e-6

  axes = tuple(range(1, len(y_pred.shape) - 1))
  numerator = 2. * K.sum(y_pred * y_true, axes)
  denominator = K.sum(K.square(y_pred) + K.square(y_true), axes)

 return 1 - K.mean(numerator / (denominator + epsilon))
```

So normally, it calculates the dice loss, but from time to time it should randomly return a `nan`. However, this does not seem to happen:

[image: keras outputs]

From time to time though, when I try to run the code, it stops right at the start (before the first epoch) with an error, saying that `An operation has None for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined`

Does that mean, that the the random function of Keras is just evaluated once and then always returns the same value?
If so, why is that and how can I create a loss function that returns `nan` from time to time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first conditional statement is only evaluated once the loss function is defined (i.e. called; that is why Keras stops right at the start). Instead, you could use [keras.backend.switch](https://keras.io/backend/#switch) to integrate your conditional into the graph's logic. Your loss function could be something along the lines of:

```
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np


def soft_dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    epsilon = 1e-6
    axes = tuple(range(1, len(y_pred.shape) - 1))
    numerator = 2. * K.sum(y_pred * y_true, axes)
    denominator = K.sum(K.square(y_pred) + K.square(y_true), axes)
    loss = 1 - K.mean(numerator / (denominator + epsilon))

    return K.switch(condition=K.random_normal((), mean=0, stddev=1) > 3,
                    then_expression=K.variable(np.nan),
                    else_expression=loss)
```